# How can I query a postgreSQL Table that uses an index?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to view IPS alerts from snort, the alerts are being inserted into the database via barnyard2. https://github.com/firnsy/barnyard2

When I use `SELECT ip_src from iphdr ;` get this back from postgresql;

```
   ip_src   
------------
 2886730039
 2886730039
 1815870597
 1815870597
 3325194354
 3325194354
```

Is it safe to assume that these are some sort of index numbers? It's obviously not in standard IPv4 form.

When the table was created, an index was also created.

```
CREATE TABLE iphdr  ( sid     INT4 NOT NULL,
                      cid     INT8 NOT NULL,
                      ip_src      INT8 NOT NULL,
                      ip_dst      INT8 NOT NULL,
                      ip_ver      INT2,
                      ip_hlen     INT2,
                      ip_tos      INT2,
                      ip_len      INT4,
                      ip_id       INT4,
                      ip_flags    INT2,
                      ip_off      INT4,
                      ip_ttl      INT2,
                      ip_proto    INT2 NOT NULL,
                      ip_csum     INT4,
                      PRIMARY KEY (sid,cid));
CREATE INDEX ip_src_idx ON iphdr (ip_src);
CREATE INDEX ip_dst_idx ON iphdr (ip_dst);
```

How do I query this table and get the actual IP address from this index?

Comment: ip_src is defined as type int8, so you're inserting integers into that column, and getting integers back out, so where exactly is your problem?  Also, although we ipv4 addresses are formatted as mmm.nnn.ooo.ppp for easier visual consumption, they are in fact a 32 bits int.  Can you show the code you use for inserting data into that field?

Comment: Updated the original post, I hope this answers your question. I guess I need to loo at this src code to see how they are inserting this?

Comment: yes, that's what you need to do.  I already answered and suggest to use the proper datatype, but that won't be a solution for you I'm afraid, if you have no control over incoming data.  Give me 2 minutes please to figure out a workaround.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An obvious solution would be to use the proper datatype, ie [the Postgres `inet` datatype](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-net-types.html)

```
CREATE TABLE iphdr  ( sid     INT4 NOT NULL,
                      cid     INT8 NOT NULL,
                      ip_src      inet NOT NULL,
                      ip_dst      inet NOT NULL,
```

which will allow you to insert network addresses literally:

```
insert into iphdr (ip_src, ip_dst) values ('192.168.0.1','192.168.0.2')
```

If you use this datatype, there are [several specialized functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-net.html) that will help you using them eg in where clauses.

If you have no control over incoming data, these data types can still help you to display the values in a recognizable format:

```
SELECT '0.0.0.0'::inet + ip_src as ipsrc,'0.0.0.0'::inet + ip_dst as ipdst,
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/65cc3/1)

Comment: This seems pretty strait forward I think. Just to make sure I understand, I should change the type from int8 to inet in the table. Would you think this will also require a src code change of barnyard2 to insert the actual address and not an int8 number?

Comment: @insecure-IT as I have no idea how the data go from barnyard2 to Postgres, that's impossible to answer.  It's IMO always "nicer" to use a proper datatype in the database, but the suggested workaround should be OK enough to get the job done.

Comment: SELECT '0.0.0.0'::inet + ip_src as ipsrc,'0.0.0.0'::inet + ip_dst as ipdst from iphdr; works for me. Thanks!!